# Most effecient way to display my data for fast fluid update

Tags: c#, .net, performance, listbox

I'm still getting to grips with C Sharp and .NET and I am working on an application to display data being continually read from a USB device.  I have all the USB code working and it is receiving the data updates every 5ms.  The data consists of a set of sensor values for a number of units, say 50 units with 12 sensors per unit.

Currently I am using a ListBox object to display 50 rows of data.  I'm setting the listbox mode to OwnerDrawFixed and my datasource to my data array of objects that represents the data read from the USB device (one object per row of the ListBox) and I'm using the DrawItem event to actually graphically draw each row of the list box as requested by the listbox (I'm doing it this way to enable text colouring, formatting, tidy layout etc).

In order to get the ListBox to refresh the data being displayed I'm calling periodically calling Invalidate to force it to redraw, but this is horrendously slow, and flicker unacceptably even at low frequecies such as 1 second updates never mind getting anywhere near the 5ms refresh of the sensors.

Can anyone suggest a better approach to updating the data on screen, perhaps one where I'm not drawing everything everytime or perhaps a way to tell the ListBox to only redraw a single row perhaps if the data on that row has changed?

I'm not tied to a ListBox in anyway, it's just my unfamiliarity with the .Net framework - perhaps the best solution might be to render everything to a bitmap and then blit it to the screen in a single action.

I've already read a similar question but the suggestions in there didn't really help...
[c# - fast ListBox data update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991036/c-fast-listbox-data-update)

Any alternative suggestions from experienced .net developers greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit the ListBox control and enable double-buffering is, I think, your best bet. I don't know how the ListBox paints but that should reduce flicker.

(If that doesn't work, a hack is to invalidate only a tiny rectangle on the corner and hope it paints properly. That most likely won't work with the original set of controls, though.)

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to make a recommendation without knowing what you are doing. You might explain what your "data", "sensor values" and "units" are. In general, graphics are better for showing large data sets than vast lists of numbers.

If this is some kind of transient data, like sound intensity, you might consider a VU-meter kind of display, like in a music player.

If you are trying to track trends or changes, consider a [sparkline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) or graph.

If you are trying to show correlations between data, consider a spectrum or XY graph.

Comment: The data is displayed in the format requested by the client.  It is mainly text which consists of a handful of numbers some decimal, some hexadecimal and then a number of flags for which I'm currently display either an X or - character (though these could easily be graphics etc).  I can't really change the layout as that is what is requested by the client which is pretty much laid out like a spreadsheet with rows and columns.

Comment: I've got to be careful not to say anything that breaches my NDA, but consider the data as 50 devices, for each I'm displaying the device number (0 to 49 - ie. row in the listbox), the serial number of the device, and then a number of flags to represent whether the switch on a sensor is open or closed.  Every device is identical, so the client has requested a spreadsheet style table representation.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you can fill ListBox at the beginig and after what just send data to layout acynchronosly.
If its posible use WPF you should try. Code is triviale when you have constant emount of data items.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested in the solution that worked for me both solidly flicker free and fast.

I simply use a Panel control to represent my table in the design view, then in my code I have a method which is triggered by a timer every 1ms (though in reality I can't seem to get it faster than every 16ms - which I guess is probably linked to the 60hz vsync refresh of the monitor because I'm doing a graphical blit).

I grab the bounds of the panel, create a bitmap of matching size, draw my data to the bitmap  using the various graphics commands (such as DrawString) then I blit the resulting bitmap to the panel control.  This works well if I then subsequently resize the window as the panel is resized and my bitmap is accordingly resized.

This also works fast, and in reality is no more work than the previous slow/flickery solution using a list control, however it is to be noted that there is not support for selecting rows etc (as this app was only using a ListBox to display data).

I'm now seriously considering mini techs suggestion for future listbox work as this work around works fantastically well, and subclassing the ListBox (rather than basing it on a Panel control) would allow me to inherit some of the row selection stuff etc.

Thanks for all the suggestions,
Rich